# Confused about this aspect of Singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I adapted my Singleton class from a tutorial I found on the web. My header looks something like:

```
class Logger{
public:
    static Logger *instance();
    ~Logger();
private:
    Logger();
    static Logger *instance_;
};
```

and the cpp file is:

```
Logger* Logger::instance_=nullptr;  //Confused about this 

Logger *Logger::instance(){
    if (instance_==nullptr){
        instance_=new Logger();
    }
    return instance_;
}

Logger::Logger(){}
```

A few questions:

1) In the first line of my cpp, if I write just "Logger::instance_=nullptr;" then I get an error. Since it's already been declared in the header, why do I need to mention that instance_ is a pointer again?

2) Why can't I initialize instance_ in the header file itself as "static Logger *instance_=nullptr;"? Doing so gives me the following error:

> error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data
>   member ‘Logger* Logger::instance_’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
>        static Logger*instance_=nullptr;
>                                   ^

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1) In the first line of my cpp, if I write just `Logger::instance_=nullptr;` then I get an error. Since it's already been declared in the header, why do I need to mention that instance_ is a pointer again?

From the C++ Draft Standard N3337:

> **9.4.2 Static data members**
>
> 5 `static` data members of a class in namespace scope have external linkage (3.5).

It's analgous to declaring

```
extern int a;
```

in a .h file and defining

```
int a = 10;
```

in a .cpp file. You have to specify the type of `a` when it's defined.

> Question 2) Why can't I initialize instance_ in the header file itself as "static Logger *instance_=nullptr;"?

From the C++ Draft Standard N3337 (emphasis mine):

> **9.4.2 Static data members**
>
> 2 The declaration of a `static` data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified `void`. **The definition for a `static` data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.** In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the `static` data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Say you have:

```
namespace detail
{
   class Foo
   {
       static int var;
   };
}
```

`Foo::var` must be defined in the enclosing `namespace` of `Foo`.

```
namespace detail
{
   int Foo:var = 0;
}
```

In the absence of an explicit enclosing namespace of a class, the global scope is it's enclosing namespace.

Comment: What does it mean for my static variable to have namespace scope here? Is it different than class scope? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both questions boils down to one thing i.e "You have to provide definition for static data members used in class explicitly in implementation file".

Answer (score 0):

**1) In the first line of my cpp, if I write just "Logger::instance_=nullptr;" then I get an error. Since it's already been declared in the header, why do I need to mention that instance_ is a pointer again?**

Because you need to be able to *define* static variables without *declaring* them first so **C++** requires the *type* information in the *definition* as well as the *declaration*.

**2) Why can't I initialize instance_ in the header file itself as "static Logger *instance_=nullptr;"?**

Because you don't want a copy of the same variable in every file that includes your header. There should only be ONE *definition* in the whole program but it needs to be *declared* every time it is accessed.